# Can I load hierarchical data with Entity Framework 4 using ".Include" and filter a Navigation Property based on some criteria

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, hierarchical-data

Hello I am using entity framework 4 and I am trying to query Customers and their Orders
as navigation property, but I only want to load the orders of a specific date.

When using this:

```
List<Customer> CustomerResults = ctx.Customers
.Include("Orders") 
.Where(
       c =>
       c.Orders.Any(od =>(od.DateTimeIn >= this.StartDateComboBox.DateTime && 
       od.DateTimeIn <= this.EndDateComboBox.DateTime))
      );
```

I get all Orders, if any of the Orders meet the criteria.

Is It possible to filter the navigation property to return only rows that meet specific criteria?

Comment: If you mean EDM .Include(Relation), that will effectively links related nodes in already loaded model, By the way, why you are doing these in such a way? Also, .Include means, that "Orders" and "Customers" have relation by some field in both database AND the model...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, there isn't.**

In short, eager-loading with `Include` automatically loads all related records (think a LEFT OUTER JOIN without a filter).

Anytime you want to filter associated records, don't use `Include` - use an anonymous type projection and EF will just "work out" what needs to be retrieved:

```
var CustomerResults = ctx.Customers 
                         .Select(x => new
                         {
                            Customer = x,
                            Orders = x.Orders.Where(y => y.DateTimeIn > value)
                         }).ToList();
```

If you want to return a `Customer` entity, then just do another projection at the end, just make sure you materialize the query first (`.ToList()`).

**EDIT - To put back into a customer object, example:**

```
var Customers = new List<Customer>();
foreach (var anonType in CustomerResults)
{
   Customer c = anonType.Customer;
   c.Orders = anonType.Orders;
   Customers.Add(c);
}
```

I'm sure you can do that with a LINQ expression, but i can't remember the syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , that is exactly the answer I was looking for. I now know that I can't filter the navigation property with Include. But the query that you sugested returns a object x that has Customer and Orders, how can I do another projection at the end to return list of Customers with the Orders?

Comment: Thank you again, i did this and it is working as expected. I hope everybody votes for your answer. I don't have the reptutation yet to vote. :(

Comment: Sorry for that, I was trying hard to find it :).

Comment: RPM, very good answer. You get my vote. I have å similar question, but I need to return in IQueryable and code in VB.NET. Please help me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079930/join-two-tables-and-filter-result-using-ef-4-and-ria-services