# Join two tables and filter result using EF 4 and RIA services

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

```
Public Function LoadSiteInfo(ByVal sId As Integer) As IQueryable(Of Site)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.Sites.Include("SiteData").Where((Function(f) f.SiteID = sId) AndAlso Function(x) x.SiteData.SiteUpdateDate < today)) 
End Function
```

So, I'm trying to filter on SiteId from the Sites table, ANDALSO on the SiteUpdateDate in the SiteData table, it's the last part where I cannot get the syntax correct - it's just saying that SiteUpdateDate attribute is not a member of ObjectContext.Site, which is correct its part of SiteData

How can I filter on attributes in the included table SiteData? Or how can I rewrite this and still return an Iquerable of Site with SiteData childtable beeing filtered as I want? Should be really easy, but I'm struggling, starting to believe that include a filtered child collection of a selected parent is not allowed... :(

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you can do it this way. You have to first return your parent with child collections.

```
Public Function LoadSiteInfo(ByVal sId As Integer) As IQueryable(Of Site)
     return FillSiteInfo(sId).Where(Function(x) x.SiteData.SiteUpdateDate < today))
End Function 

Public Function FillSiteInfo(byVal sId as Integer) as IQueryable(of Site)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.Sites.Include("SiteData").Where((Function(f) f.SiteID = sId).AsQueryable()
End Function
```

That Should work for you.

also you need to check your RIA services to make sure your Child Collection has [include] as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good with VB, so here's the C# version.

```
return this.ObjectContext
   .Sites
   .Where(x => x.SiteData.All(y => y.SiteUpdateData < today))
   .Where(x => x.SiteId == sId)
   .Select(x => new { Sites = x, SiteDatas = x.SiteData })
   .Select(x => x.Sites);
```

The trick is, you can't filter on an eager loaded property (`SiteData`), so you have to use anonymous type projection, and then project the query back into what you want.